# Array.insert function error as Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'insert'

Tags: javascript, html, httphandler

I am working with javascript, HTML, HTTPHandlers and i have used a line in javascript as

```
Array.insert( Garray, eval(firstmarker), tmparray);
```

for this line in Goggle Chrome console have found an error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'insert'

In the above line the `tmparray` contains values and the `Garray` is an array declared globally as

```
var Garray = [];
```

`eval(firstmarker)` has the position and initially that is taken as undefined but even if i pass manually 0 it shows the above error in Console.

And the `Array.Insert` method found from the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383995.aspx

I have tried alternatives for this as `Arrayname.splice` method and also `Arrayname.push`method but it is not working so Can you please help me to solve the above error.

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Don't use MSDN as a reference. It never mentions whether the method is a proprietary extension or a standard. Use MDN instead (prefix searches with "mdn" to find the correct documentation): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: ok thank u!! will use the link..... @ Rob W

Answer (score 2):

The correct method to use is [`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), for example:

```
var my_array = [];
my_array.push('apple');
```

Comment: If i use the push method for array in that place it is not showing error but later in the javascript it shows that error as :               Cannot read property 'title' of undefined which is related to the array.insert line as i have the same javascript code working in the previous build properly,but it is showing error in this new build so i would like to continue the array.insert method so is there any way that we can solve this error and continue using Array.insert method only.

Comment: @Shruthi, as far as my knowledge goes, Array.insert is not valid javascript. can you compile a short example of your problem for use on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2):

To insert an item into an array at a specific point you can use `splice()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice))  in the following way:

```
Garray.splice( firstmarker, 0, yourElement1, yourElement2, ... );
```

The alternative of `push()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) appends an element to the array:

```
Garray.push( yourElement1, yourElement2, ... );
```